# erb if conditions with environment variables

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to do something like this for a sinatra app using erb.  I've been struggling with it for quite a while and have had trouble finding good documentation for erb.  Any thoughts on how to implement a working version of this would be very much appreciated.

```
<% if employee['filename'] == nil %>
                <img width="70" height="70" src="#{ENV['no_image_url']}">
                <% else %>
                <img width="70" height="70" data-src="#{ENV['employee_image']" src="#{ENV['employee_image']">
                end
```

Comment: You simply forgot to end your if statement, I think.  `<% end %>`

Comment: @vgoff Will the string interpolation work for his `src` attributes, or will he have to use erb tags (`<%= %>`) there too?

Comment: I would probably not do environment variable wrangling in the view at all but in the Sinatra application itself.  Then use a `yield` for the result to be presented.  I was addressing the 'if statement' only.  The other functionality is whatever it is he is doing, it doesn't seem to make sense here, but I don't have any indications of what he is doing with that, perhaps it is instructional code, and meant to be shown like it is.  In other words, I only addressed the ERB portion not how it interacts with the framework of Sinatra.

Comment: To answer your question though, yes, the HTML will present that as is presented.  So erb tags would need to be used to get that to evaluate.  This is not the way to go though, the value should be determined in the program logic, rather than the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot to close out your if statement.

```
<% if employee['filename'].nil? %>
  <img width="70" height="70" src="#{ENV['no_image_url']}">
<% else %>
  <img width="70" height="70" data-src="#{ENV['employee_image']" src="#{ENV['employee_image']">
<% end %>
```

This really doesn't seem like a good design, though.  Build the image code for rendering in your application code, and then render that result in your view.  Then you will not have the conditional code in your view at all, you will render the result, and it will be simpler code.

Answer (score 1):

This working for me in html.erb file

```
 <a href="<%= ENV.fetch('variable') %>"></a> with fetch
 <a href="<%= ENV['variable'] %>"></a> with out fetch
```